# New Magento 2.0.0 module gives error: Setup version not specified

Tags: magento2, module, error, magento-2.0, setup-upgrade

After creating a new module in `Magento 2.0.0`,

I am getting this below error:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:64:"Setup version for module 'Trimantra_HelloWorld' is not specified";i:1;s:2337:"#0 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(56): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('Trimantra_Hello...', false)
#1 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(79): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('Trimantra_Hello...')
#2 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(55): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors()
#3 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCookieVali...')
#6 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Plugin/StoreCookie.php(78): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 [internal function]: Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#12 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/index.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:132:"/magento/magento2.0/admin/admin/system_config/edit/section/dev/key/bac1443deb92fa33b3b61828bf3918c5dc7afe8e42d5f7eb69344bbc843927a5/";s:11:"script_name";s:29:"/magento/magento2.0/index.php";}
```

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

every module need to specify `setup_version`

```
setup_version="1.0.0"
```

update your `module.xml` file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Trimantra_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0">      
    </module>
</config>
```

and then clear cache `php bin/magento cache:clean` and update modules `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0


                                                           
  [InvalidArgumentException]                               
  There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.   i am getting this error after running this command

Comment: @murtuza, otherwise go to admin panel `System->Cache Management` clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Did you execute:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

after you enabled the module? This error is thrown when Magento cannot find a setup version for the module.

Comment: PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0


                                                           
  [InvalidArgumentException]                               
  There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.  i am getting this error after running this command

Comment: after upgrade im getting this error

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Can't create directory /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.' in /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:103 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Framewo...') #1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 [internal function]:

Comment: Looks like a cache problem, can you remove cache: rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/*

Comment: nup this is not cache problem

Comment: The "There are no commands defined in the cache namespace" error can be resolved by running `bin/magento module:enable --all`